# Firebase Cloud Messaging of Unity causes crashes on Android at application launch (once)

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, crash, firebase-cloud-messaging

In July 2021, Google has instructed Unity developers to  [Migrate from UPM packages to Asset packages](https://developers.google.com/unity/instructions#migrate), Since I upgraded my unity game project and used Asset packages instead of UPM, I am seeing about 10% crashes on Android devices (log at the end of the question).

The problem seems to be caused by Firebase Cloud Messaging and I'm guessing that it happens only when a new version of the game is installed on top of a previously installed version. And after closing and re-opening the application the problem fades away, I don't experience any crashes afterward.

I cannot go back to using UPM because Google does not provide updates through UPM anymore, and old SDKs won't work properly.

I am using the latest Unity 2019.4 (currently .30f), IL2CPP, .NET 4.x, Minimum API 21 (5). I use the NDK/SDK that comes installed with the Unity Android module.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: The problem only happens on Firebase versions after v8.x.x. I just rolled back to a version before v8.x.x and the crashes disappeared. I'm currently using version 7.2.0 of Firebase.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.Error FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain] Unity
> version : 2019.4.30f1 Device model : ZTE ZTE BLADE V8 MINI Device
> fingerprint:
> ZTE/P840F01_MX_ATT/ZTE_BLADE_V0850:7.0/NRD90M/20170602.144530:user/release-keys

> Caused by java.lang.Error
> *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** Version '2019.4.30f1 (e8c891080a1f)', Build type 'Release', Scripting
> Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a' Build fingerprint:
> 'ZTE/P840F01_MX_ATT/ZTE_BLADE_V0850:7.0/NRD90M/20170602.144530:user/release-keys'
> Revision: '0' ABI: 'arm64' Timestamp: 2021-10-15 21:23:49-0500 pid:
> 19756, tid: 20100, name: Thread-93 >>> com.infinitygames.pipes <<<
> uid: 10649 signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
> Cause: null pointer dereference x0 0000000000000008 x1
> 0000007e4f9fe490 x2 0000000000000004 x3 0000007e4f9fe509 x4
> 0000007e4f9fe448 x5 0000000080000000 x6 0000008000000000 x7
> 5e6f5e20fffefefe x8 0000000000000000 x9 6472606164716865 x10
> 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f x11 0101010101010101 x12 0000000000000018 x13
> 00000000ffffffff x14 00000000000cb140 x15 2e8ba2e8ba2e8ba3 x16
> 0000007e4fff13a8 x17 0000007fa5ee4d98 x18 00000000ffffffff x19
> 0000000000000000 x20 0000007e4f9fe490 x21 0000007e4f9fe448 x22
> 0000000000000000 x23 0000007e4f9fe509 x24 0000000000000004 x25
> 0000000000000008 x26 0000007e4f9fe508 x27 0000000000000001 x28
> 0000007e4ea92c90 x29 0000007e4f9fe778 sp 0000007e4f9fe3f0 lr
> 0000007e4fec43ac pc 0000007fa5ee4d98 backtrace: #00 pc
> 0000000000068d98 /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock) (BuildId:
> 359947b8d684fe3e8ea897ca5e978f06) #01 pc 00000000001fe3a8
> /data/app/com.infinitygames.pipes-1/lib/arm64/libFirebaseCppApp-8_3_0.so
> (firebase::Mutex::Acquire()+4) (BuildId:
> 8209be713e18b8cc0f0f9cdc20b6d1f4) #02 pc 0000000000203c8c
> /data/app/com.infinitygames.pipes-1/lib/arm64/libFirebaseCppApp-8_3_0.so
> (void
> firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteInternal<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
> std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator >, void
> firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteWithResultInternal<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
> std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator > >
> (firebase::FutureHandle const&, int, char const*, std<truncated: 1671 chars>

> libc.pthread_mutex_lock (pthread_mutex_lock)
> libFirebaseCppApp-8_3_0.firebase::Mutex::Acquire() (Acquire:4)
> libFirebaseCppApp-8_3_0.void
> firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteInternal<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
> std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator >, void
> firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteWithResultInternal<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
> std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator >
>
> > (firebase::FutureHandle const&, int, char const*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits,
> > std::__ndk1::allocator >
> > const&)::'lambda'(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
> > std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator
> > *)>(firebase::FutureHandle const&, int, char const*, void firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteWithResultInternal<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
> > std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator >
> > (firebase::FutureHandle const&, int, char const*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits,
> > std::__ndk1::allocator >
> > const&)::'lambda'(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
> > std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator >*)
> > const&) (allocator > >:44) libFirebaseCppApp-8_3_0.void
> > firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteWithResultInternal<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
> > std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator >
> > (firebase::FutureHandle const&, int, char const*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits,
> > std::__ndk1::allocator > const&) (allocator > >:64)
> > libFirebaseCppApp-8_3_0.firebase::messaging::CompleteStringCallback(_JNIEnv*,
> > _jobject*, firebase::util::FutureResult, char const*, void*) (CompleteStringCallback:136)
> > libFirebaseCppApp-8_3_0.firebase::util::JniResultCallback_nativeOnResult(_JNIEnv*,
> > _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned char, unsigned char, _jstring*, long, long) (JniResultCallback_nativeOnResult:172) app_resources_lib.0x6098

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @Dr-Bracket Yes, Just roll back your Firebase SDK back to a version before v8. I am using 7.2.0 and it works well.

Comment: @AmirKhavari Could you please post this to their github also? We have a very similar issue.